# How to convert specially formated string to double

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In Java, how do I convert a string representation of a specially formatted double to double?

For example, 1.00 is represented as 1d-2 while 1.25 is represented as 1.25?

Thanks

Comment: 1.00 = 1. Trailing zeros make no difference.

Comment: You have to parse the format.  Exactly how depends on the format.  I have never seen `1d-2` = `1.00` before.  BTW For a double 1 = 1.0 = 1.00 = 1.000

Comment: What format is 1d-2?  What class is creating that string representation?  (Normally, I'd say use NumberFormat but this doesn't appear to be what you are using.)

Comment: I did not create the string that represents 1.00 as 1d-2. It is just fed to me in the json blob I am receiving. I need to convert it to 1.

Comment: So just do a little check? `if(input.equals("1d-2") return 1;`

Comment: You are going to need to find out what that format is in order to decide what to do with it.  Ask whomever created the string and wrote it to JSON.  Or the library it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow convert that 1d-2 into a proper double (ex. 1.0 or 1.5) then just use double.parseDouble();

Comment: I was wondering if there was a function in Java that could do the conversion from 1d-2 to 1 for me.

Comment: No, sorry not that I am aware of. However, How are you getting 1d-2?? I would have asked that in the original question but no enough rep :(

Comment: I am calling a web service and the strange format is part of the response.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to the web service or explain how that strange format works (If you know).